# Config 2 EC2 that have mongoDb to work together

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I create 2 micro ec2 with mongoDB install on each one of them,
The same zone and i want to configure that one will be mater and the rest is slave,
How to configure mongodb.conf ?

Thanks .

Comment: Are you using Replica Sets? Master-Slave has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation:

- [Amazon EC2 Quickstart](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Amazon+EC2+Quickstart)
- [Amazon EC2 with MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Amazon+EC2)